# Node.js Gmail API draft with attachment not working

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail-api, nodemailer

I'm trying to create a simple draft with PDF attachment in Node.js using Gmail API.
The draft is created and shown in Gmail but it doesn't have the attachment. Also, when clicking on the draft in Gmail, it opens an empty draft with no title or content.
When I'm trying to send an email using pretty much the same code it's working perfectly.

This is my code:

```
const createMailEncodedMessage = async (params) => {
    const msg = await buildMailBody(params)

    // The body needs to be base64url encoded.
    const encodedMessage = Buffer.from(msg)
        .toString('base64')
        .replace(/\+/g, '-')
        .replace(/\//g, '_')
        .replace(/=+$/, '')

    return encodedMessage
}

const sendEmail = async (params) => {
    if (!auth) {
        await init()
    }

    const encodedMessage = await createMailEncodedMessage(params)
    return await gmail.users.messages.send({
        userId: 'me',
        requestBody: {
            raw: encodedMessage,
        },
    })
}

const createDraft = async (params) => {
    if (!auth) {
        await init()
    }

    const encodedMessage = await createMailEncodedMessage(params)

    return await gmail.users.drafts.create({
        userId: 'me',
        requestBody: {
            message: {
                raw: encodedMessage,
            }
        }
    })
}

const buildMailBody = ({ from, to, subject, body, attachments }) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let mail = new MailComposer({
            from,
            to,
            //text: 'I hope this works',
            html: body,
            subject,
            textEncoding: 'base64',
            attachments: attachments?.map(a => ({
                filename: a.fileName,
                content: fs.createReadStream(a.filePath),
            })),
        })

        mail.compile().build((error, msg) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error)
            }

            resolve(msg)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: In order to replicate your issue, could you please share a complete example? Also, are you able to create a draft without attachments? Please clarify if you receive any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing this question I developed a code that you can use to reach your goal. This script will send an email with [`users.messages.send`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send) with two example attachments. I used the credentials flow described on the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) to manage the token and scope. Please keep in mind that you would need a method to handle email MIME types and base64 conversion. For the sake of making a working example, I used the MailComposer library to control the MIME types. The following script should work as is, you only need to set up the credentials to make it run (you could use the steps described on the quickstart):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {
  google
} = require('googleapis');
const MailComposer = require('nodemailer/lib/mail-composer');
const SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), sendEmailWithAttachments);
});

function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {
    client_secret,
    client_id,
    redirect_uris
  } = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token',
        err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

function sendEmailWithAttachments(auth) {
  let mail = new MailComposer({
    to: "{ RECIPIENT EMAIL }",
    text: "Morbi imperdiet gravida leo in commodo.",
    html: "Morbi <i>imperdiet</i> gravida <b>leo</b> in commodo.",
    subject: "Donec et porttitor erat",
    textEncoding: "base64",
    attachments: [{
        filename: 'attachment1.txt',
        content: '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',
        encoding: 'base64'
      },
      {
        filename: 'attachment2.txt',
        content: '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',
        encoding: 'base64'
      },
    ]
  });
  
  mail.compile().build((error, msg) => {
    if (error) return console.log('ERROR - ' + error);
    const encodedMessage = Buffer.from(msg).toString('base64').replace(
      /\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, '');
    const gmail = google.gmail({
      version: 'v1',
      auth
    });
    gmail.users.messages.send({
      userId: 'me',
      resource: {
        raw: encodedMessage,
      }
    }, (err, result) => {
      if (err) return console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
      console.log("Email sent: ", result.data);
    });
  })
}
```

The script works in two steps. First, it uses the library to build an email compatible with the standard MIME types. Secondly, it calls the Gmail API using the previously built email. If the email is sent successfully, the API will return its IDs and labels. Please leave a comment to clarify any doubt.